# What is the significance of having the correct hostname for a cloud server in the control panel of the hosting company

Tags: cloud, hostname

What could be a problem that could arise if i do not have the correct hostname as my device name for the cloud server in a control panel of my hosting company

basically the device name is supposedly the hostname

when i created the cloud server they ensured this was my hostname for my new cloud server. but it looks like they will not allow me to use a domain name that is all digits.

currently my host name in the cloud server itself is a domain name that is all digits.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a question for the hosting company and/or a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two usages for the name in the control panel:

- Used for reverse DNS.
- For reference, such that it is clear, which host is being talked about.

If it is only for reference, having an exactly correct name is not important. If it is used for reverse DNS, a correct name may be important, in particular if you need to send mail you should make sure everything matches up exactly right.

You can have multiple names for the same machine. I would recommend that the primary name starts with a letter. You can have a secondary domain name, which starts with a digit. That secondary domain name I would put only in forward DNS (as well as in vhost configuration, if applicable). For the actual hostname and reverse DNS, I recommend using the primary name, which starts with a letter.